# In Java FTP-Can we compress a file in remote location using ftp, without bringing the file to local machine?

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

Can we compress a file in remote location using ftp, without bringing the file to local machine?

I am doing a POC , in which i want to compress a text or csv file located in remote machine, In java there is program for compression which i use to compress the files located in local machine,
My requirement is i need to compress the file in the remote location without bringing it to the local machine , is it achievable in java?

Awaiting for the reply from the genius

Comment: Unless you can ask the FTP server to make calls to the system shell, I can't really see how this would be possible.  You would be able to do this with a secure shell (nb- My experience with FTP is reasonably limited to just pure old file copying...)

Comment: What exactly does FTP have to do with it? FTP is a File Transfer Protocol, not a remote file compression system.

Comment: thanks @MadProgrammer for ur reply, By the way you have mentioned SHELL programming does it have anything related to SFTP(SSH) or its OS level programming in linux box,Can you just explain this context a little more.

Comment: @EJP here i am trying to extend the functionality of FTP with  additional compression logic, Can it be achieved as Madprogrammer said or do u have any ideas kindly, share your thoughts in this..

Comment: The shell is the remote OS environment.  If you can use something like SSH (secure shell), you can execute OS level commands on the remote machine, which are carried out within the context of the remote machine.  If I recall properly, you can even perform file transfer (but that might have being the library I was using)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your server supports SITE commands. If it does, it is possible that those commands are somehow passed to the shell for execution, thus giving you required shell access. Otherwise there's no standard way to use FTP protocol for your task.