# How to compress file in SFTP or FTP server by using Java?

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch, zip

I am able to compress files in my local computer, but I want to compress (.zip) files in SFTP server through Java. How can I pass URL and how to compress the files in SFTP or FTP server?

Below one is my local system working same thing I need to implement in SFTP.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class CompressToZip {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String pattern = "ddMMyyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(date);
        String sourceFolderName =  "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\BackUpFiles\\"+date;

        File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\BackUpFileZip");
        String outputFileName = folder+"\\"+date+".zip";
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Folder Exist.....");
        }


        System.currentTimeMillis();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        //level - the compression level (0-9)
        zos.setLevel(9);

        System.out.println("Begin to compress folder : " + sourceFolderName + " to " + outputFileName);
        addFolder(zos, sourceFolderName, sourceFolderName);

        zos.close();
        System.out.println("Program ended successfully!");
    }

    private static void addFolder(ZipOutputStream zos,String folderName,String baseFolderName)throws Exception{
        File f = new File(folderName);
        if(f.exists()){

            if(f.isDirectory()){
                //Thank to peter 
                //For pointing out missing entry for empty folder
                if(!folderName.equalsIgnoreCase(baseFolderName)){
                    String entryName = folderName.substring(baseFolderName.length()+1,folderName.length()) + File.separatorChar;
                    System.out.println("Adding folder entry " + entryName);
                    ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(entryName);
                    zos.putNextEntry(ze);    
                }
                File f2[] = f.listFiles();
                for(int i=0;i<f2.length;i++){
                    addFolder(zos,f2[i].getAbsolutePath(),baseFolderName);    
                }
            }else{
                //add file
                //extract the relative name for entry purpose
                String entryName = folderName.substring(baseFolderName.length()+1,folderName.length());
                System.out.print("Adding file entry " + entryName + "...");
                ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(entryName);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(folderName);
                int len;
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                zos.closeEntry();
                System.out.println("OK!");

            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("File or directory not found " + folderName);
        }

    }

}
```

How can I give the `sourceFolderName` and `outputFileName` of SFTP or FTP server address?

For connecting to SFTP I am using below code:

```
public class JschTestDownload {

  public static void main(String s[]) {

       JSch jsch = new JSch();

       Session session = null;
       // Remote machine host name or IP
       String hostName = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx";
       // User name to connect the remote machine
       String userName = "xxxxx";
       // Password for remote machine authentication
       String password = "xxxx";    
       // Source file path on local machine
       String srcFilePath = "/Inbound/testSFTP.txt";
       // Destination directory location on remote machine

       String destinationLocation = "C:/Users/Desktop/SftpUpDown/TestDownload";
       try {
        // Getting the session
        session = jsch.getSession(userName, hostName,22);

        // Ignore HostKeyChecking
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");                  

        // set the password for authentication
        session.setPassword(password);
        System.out.println("try to get the connection");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("got the connection");            
        // Getting the channel using sftp
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        sftpChannel.cd("/Inbound/");


        // Exist the channel
         sftpChannel.exit();

         // Disconnect the session
         session.disconnect();

       } catch (JSchException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();

       } catch (SftpException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
}
```

By using above code I am able to get file and put file. But I want to compress file in SFTP server by using first code. I need to run that code in my computer and compress file at server and download to my computer.
How can I do it? Give me some guidance.

Comment: how can I give file path of SFTP server like this "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\BackUpFiles\\"+date".("sftp://userName:pssword@Address/foldername/")

Comment: No idea, what you mean? Like what? Where do you want to give the path to?

Comment: String sourceFolderName =  "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\BackUpFiles\\"+date;     File f = new File(sourceFolderName );

Comment: No you cannot. And even if you could (like e.g. PHP can with its protocol wrappers), it would not change anything. It would still download the file behind the scenes. You cannot circumvent capabilities of the protocol by any syntax trick!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. There's no way to compress files in-place over the FTP or SFTP protocol.

All you can do is to download the file, compress locally and upload back. What you seem to be able to do.

That does not mean you have to store the file locally (temporarily). You can do all this in memory, using streams.

---

Of course, if you have a shell access to the server, you can connect with the SSH protocol and run a `zip` (or similar) command to compress the files. But that's not SFTP/FTP.

---

Related questions:

- [In Java FTP-Can we compress a file in remote location using ftp, without bringing the file to local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20486929/850848)
- [Unzip file on SFTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39284899/850848)
- [Is it possible to create a zip file from a folder stored at remote location using SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37773295/850848)
- [Python script for creating zip file in remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33406850/850848)

Comment: Is it possible to do it through ip address, means that system is connected in my network. And also tell me the commend for making zip without disturbing the original file.

Comment: *"Is it possible to do it through ip address, means that system is connected in my network"* - What does this mean? - *"commend for making zip without disturbing the original file"* - We do not know what your remote operating system is, what shell does it use - What tools does it have installed. Give us some information.

Comment: Is it possible to do it through ip address, means that system is connected in my network : local network system

Comment: That does not mean anything. If all you have is an IP address, it does not matter if the machine is in local network or anywhere on the Internet. What matters is what services the server offers. Though, if the machine is on a local network, I do not see, what is the problem with downloading and uploading back? It should be quick.

Comment: that files size is more 100 GB per day so that need to compress and download. if I am able to compress, it will come under 20 GB only.

Comment: No you cannot. Again, except by running some command on the server, if you have a shell access - or anything similar - like PowerShell remoting, if it is a Windows server - If you have a SFTP access, it's pretty common that you have some kind of shell access - and if not, it should be easy to allow it (as it seems to be "your" server) - Though that's not a programming question.

Comment: Ok,Thanks you so much for your suggestions and guidance.